# Suppress or remove columns named 'index' from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe from three parent (or source) dataframes (each created from a .csv file), but when writing the resulting dataframe to a file or printing on screen, columns named 'index' are showing up. How do I suppress/delete them?

**The three 'parent' dataframes:**

```
df1 ...
   fname  lname employer  score1  score2  score3
0  Alice  Adams      IMB    -1.0     2.5    -0.2
1  Alice  Brown      MFS     2.2    -7.9     3.7
2  Alice   Curt      OCR     2.6    -1.2    -0.7

df2 ...
   fname  lname employer  score1  score2  score3
0  Alice  Adams      IMB     3.0     0.1    -2.9
1  Alice  Brown      MFS    -2.1     2.6    -1.0
2  Alice   Curt      OCR     3.1     1.9    -0.1

df3 ...
   fname  lname employer  score1  score2  score3
0  Alice  Adams      IMB    -1.0    -2.1     0.1
1  Alice  Brown      MFS     3.2    -0.9     5.1
2  Alice   Curt      OCR    -1.1    -1.2    -1.9
```

**After a bunch of operations, I get this:**

```
   fname  lname  index employer  score1  index employer  score3  index employer  score1  index employer  score3  index employer  score1  index employer  score3
0  Alice  Adams      0      IMB    -1.0      2      OCR    -0.7      1      MFS    -2.1      0      IMB    -2.9      2      OCR    -1.1      2      OCR    -1.9
1  Alice  Brown      1      MFS     2.2      0      IMB    -0.2      0      IMB     3.0      1      MFS    -1.0      0      IMB    -1.0      0      IMB     0.1
2  Alice   Curt      2      OCR     2.6      1      MFS     3.7      2      OCR     3.1      2      OCR    -0.1      1      MFS     3.2      1      MFS     5.1
```

**What I am looking for:**
*Get rid of columns named 'index'.*

I have a MWE from which I pasted the above results. Let me know if you'd like to see the source .csv and .py files here.

**ADDENDUM**
Posting the source .csv files and the .py script:

```
A.csv ...  
fname,lname,employer,score1,score2,score3
Alice,Adams,IMB,-1.0,2.5,-0.2
Alice,Brown,MFS,2.2,-7.9,3.7
Alice,Curt,OCR,2.6,-1.2,-0.7

B.csv ...
fname,lname,employer,score1,score2,score3
Alice,Adams,IMB,3.0,0.1,-2.9
Alice,Brown,MFS,-2.1,2.6,-1.0
Alice,Curt,OCR,3.1,1.9,-0.1

C.csv ...
fname,lname,employer,score1,score2,score3
Alice,Adams,IMB,-1.0,-2.1,0.1
Alice,Brown,MFS,3.2,-0.9,5.1
Alice,Curt,OCR,-1.1,-1.2,-1.9
```

Now, the .py script ...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import fnmatch
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

Datasets = ['A', 'B', 'C']
bigDF = pd.DataFrame()

for fname in Datasets:
    if fname == 'A':
        csvdf = pd.read_csv(fname+'.csv')
        csvdfBUa = csvdf[['fname', 'lname']]
        csvdfBUb = csvdf[['employer', 'score1']]
        csvdfBUb = csvdfBUb.sort(['score1'], ascending=[1])
        csvdfBUb = csvdfBUb.reset_index()
        csvdfBUc = csvdf[['employer', 'score3']]
        csvdfBUc = csvdfBUc.sort(['score3'], ascending=[1])
        csvdfBUc = csvdfBUc.reset_index()
        csvdfBU = pd.concat([csvdfBUa, csvdfBUb, csvdfBUc], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
        print csvdf
        if len(bigDF.index) < 1:
            bigDF = csvdfBU
        else:
            bigDF = pd.concat([bigDF, csvdfBU], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
    elif fname == 'B':
        csvdf = pd.read_csv(fname+'.csv')
        csvdfAFb = csvdf[['employer', 'score1']]
        csvdfAFb = csvdfAFb.sort(['score1'], ascending=[1])
        csvdfAFb = csvdfAFb.reset_index()
        csvdfAFc = csvdf[['employer', 'score3']]
        csvdfAFc = csvdfAFc.sort(['score3'], ascending=[1])
        csvdfAFc = csvdfAFc.reset_index()
        csvdfAF = pd.concat([csvdfAFb, csvdfAFc], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
        print csvdf
        if len(bigDF.index) < 1:
            bigDF = csvdfAF
        else:
            bigDF = pd.concat([bigDF, csvdfAF], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
    elif fname == 'C':
        csvdf = pd.read_csv(fname+'.csv')
        csvdfGAb = csvdf[['employer', 'score1']]
        csvdfGAb = csvdfGAb.sort(['score1'], ascending=[1])
        csvdfGAb = csvdfGAb.reset_index()
        csvdfGAc = csvdf[['employer', 'score3']]
        csvdfGAc = csvdfGAc.sort(['score3'], ascending=[1])
        csvdfGAc = csvdfGAc.reset_index()
        csvdfGA = pd.concat([csvdfGAb, csvdfGAc], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
        print csvdf
        if len(bigDF.index) < 1:
            bigDF = csvdfGA
        else:
            bigDF = pd.concat([bigDF, csvdfGA], axis=1, ignore_index=False)

print bigDF
```

Comment: Does `del df["index"]` not work?  (I'm using a recent development version and lots of things have changed since 0.12 was released, so it's hard for me to check at the moment-- I think some duplicate column behaviour has changed.)

Comment: @DSM I answered before seeing yours, but you can use mangle_dupe_cols=False

Comment: What is the resulting DataFrame suppose to mean (are you sure you've done the "bunch of operations" correctly?)

Comment: What commands are you using to combine these three dataframes ? You could try to get rid of them in the process.

Comment: @AndyHayden Updated the post, please see the Addendum. The resulting dataframe collates data collected under three distinct conditions, sorting the 'employer' by ascending score1 **as well as** (not AND) score3 for **each** condition. Hence, repetition of the 'employer' column.

Comment: @fixxxer Updated post. Also, please see my reply to AndyHayden.

Answer (score 5):

You can delete the "index" columns using:

```
del df['index']
```

*Note: I suspect you could avoid this in the first place...*

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df[np.negative(pd.Series(df.columns).str.contains('index'))]
```

Comment: Won't `df.index` refer to the "vertical" index, not the columns named index?  I'd've thought the OP was looking for something more like `df.loc[:,df.columns != "index"]`.

Comment: @dmvianna Sorry, no go. I get this error: `AssertionError: cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [FloatBlock: [score1, score3, score1, score3, score1, score3], 6 x 2, dtype float64] with duplicate items [Index([u'fname', u'lname', u'index', u'employer', u'score1', u'index', u'employer', u'score3', u'index', u'employer', u'score1', u'index', u'employer', u'score3', u'index', u'employer', u'score1', u'index', u'employer', u'score3'], dtype=object)] does not have _ref_locs set`

Comment: @DSM Using your example `code` in reply to dmvianna, results in this error: `KeyError: Exception('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects',)`

Comment: @shiven: that might be one of the things which has recently changed.  It works for me.

Comment: @DSM's alternative works for me. And you're right, my code didn't. It works now, albeit not very elegantly. :P